# OpenVPN Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I get this error when trying connect to server

```
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869561 my_ip:49327 TCPv4_SERVER READ [54] from [AF_INET]my_ip:49327: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #1 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869743 my_ip:49327 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]my_ip:49327, sid=7e1d5645 775455fc
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869793 my_ip:49327 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869812 my_ip:49327 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]my_ip:49327
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869849 my_ip:49327 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869861 my_ip:49327 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Tue Apr 24 16:03:16 2018 us=869958 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

server.conf
https://pastebin.com/tqE3b6gr

client.conf
https://pastebin.com/jGuywbTs

I tried solution from there [OpenVPN HMAC Authentication Failure No Matter What I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594868/openvpn-hmac-authentication-failure-no-matter-what-i-do) but it doesnt work with me

Is there any solution for this? Maybe this depends on OS or hosting. Because i  copied  previous config from my working aws Ubuntu 16.04 instance to another Ubuntu 14.04 but that config on this sever didnt work too.